# Django registration with a phone number

Tags: django, django-models, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django project and a Django REST in the backend and vue js on the client side. I want to use my phone number for registration and login quality. How can I do this if I'm sorry if someone is doing it earlier? I will be happy for your advice, and sorry for my English.

Error using Django-phone-login:

> File "/home/c2dent/django/afmoon/backend/afmoon/urls.py", line 24, in 
>       url(r'^phone_login/', include('phone_login.urls', namespace='phone_login'),),
>     File "/home/c2dent/django-trunk/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
>       'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
>   c2dent@c2dent:~/django/afmoon/backend$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
>   SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>   ERRORS:
>   : (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'phone_number', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PhoneTokenAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'phone_login.PhoneToken'.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna write your own Authentication backend for that.

first of all state your custom backend path in the project settings.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('core.backends.EmailOrPhoneModelBackend',)
```

Then in a separate doc "backends.py" you can write your own logic. Below is my own solution.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import MyUser


class EmailOrPhoneModelBackend(ModelBackend):

#This is a ModelBacked that allows authentication with either a username or an email address.

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    if '@' in username:
        kwargs = {'email': username}
    else:
        kwargs = {'phone': username}
    try:
        user = MyUser.objects.get(**kwargs)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, username):
    try:
        return MyUser.objects.get(pk=username)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Above is the solution for registration with either email or phone no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A for registration by phone number via SMS confirmation, how can I do it?

Comment: At first set inactive, after sms confirmation you will set active, else user will retry to activate account. SMS confirmation will change status of user, not affect to registration process.

Comment: You can auto generate a 4 digit code and send it to the client using a backend [like this](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-sendsms) and verify it when they send you the code.

Comment: There are also services like 'twilio' and 'nexmo' who provide sms services for authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll try to do it that way, as a beginner so I need time to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Django Phone Login](https://github.com/wejhink/django-phone-login), let me know if you need help with the setup.

Comment: I tried this but could not implement it, because after setting up and setting settings.py I showed a lot of errors. And I did not know how to fix it.

Comment: And there is no article shown how to write models.py and how to implement it using Djnago Phone Login?

Comment: Here is the error: <class 'phone_login.admin.PhoneTokenAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'phone_number', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PhoneTokenAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'phone_login.PhoneToken'

Comment: @user9922491 you can solve this issue by doing:
pip install -U django-phonenumber-field